# Toggle button android

Tags: android, toggle

I want my toggle button's ON text to be large and OFF text to be small. But can't do it.. any suggestions? This is what i was trying

```
mf=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.mf);

        if(mf.isEnabled()==true)
        {
            mf.setTextSize(13);
        }
        else
            mf.setTextSize(8);
```

Comment: I think that code its ok. Where do you change the size? In the main activity or in other thread/class ?

Comment: main activity .. code 's not running

Comment: You can use `if (mf.isEnabled())` instead of `if(mf.isEnabled()==true)`.

Comment: Its true, the problem is that call. The correct method is mf.isChecked()

Comment: @muffinbubble nope.. it makes no difference.. same result!

Comment: @aracem: nope.. tried it already!

Comment: We need more information. What happend when you push the button? error? Put us the log.

Comment: @ross Comment was more for info really, not a solution. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your code has to be called each time you click on your button. so use :

```
toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (toggleButton.isChecked()) {
            toggleButton.setTextSize(13.0f);
        } else {
            toggleButton.setTextSize(8.0f);
        }
    }
});
```

You can set OnClickListner with a easy method. In your .xml put the option

```
android:onClick="nameOfMethod"
```

And then in your code:

```
public void nameOfMethod(View v){

}
```

Where v is the togglebutton in this case ( ToggleButton mf = (ToggleButton)v;  )

Comment: Or if you have already a function called when you click on your button, put the code inside this function :)

Comment: I assumed that @ross put the code inside onclick but good apreciation

Comment: I assumed the same too. I guess we shouldn't!

Comment: Yeah, I tried it and it works on my phone, so I thought he might have not put it insind onClick.

Comment: Nice addition Aracem, +1 Zoleas.

Answer (score 4):

I put the solution here:

```
 mf=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.mf);

    if(mf.isChecked())
    {
        mf.setTextSize(13);
    }
    else
        mf.setTextSize(8);
```

Use isChecked() instead of isEnabled()

Comment: Need more information. Logs if a error ocurs... check if R.id.mf ist ok

Answer (score 3):

You need to do some debugging.

Firstly:

```
if(mf.isEnabled()==true)
```

can be

```
if (mf.isEnabled())
```

Does `mf.setTextSize(13)` on it's own work as expected?

Add some logging:

```
    if (mf.isEnabled())
    {
        // Add some logging, is this line reached correctly?
        mf.setTextSize(13);
    }
    else
        // Add some logging, is this line reached correctly?
        mf.setTextSize(8);
```

Chances are you need to change `isEnabled()` to `isChecked()`. `isEnabled()` means exactly that, whether it's enabled or not. You want to know whether the button has been checked.

Comment: yes.. mf.setTextSize(13) works.. but neither do isEnabled or isChecked do .. and isEnabled alwaz is true.... so it sets the size to 13px

Comment: Zoleas' answer is probably correct, you need to set `toggleButton.setOnClickListener`.